# How to retrieve all query params from the URL which has a redirect URL as one of param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, query-string

I have below logic to retrieve query PARAM form the application URL. But this logic is not working when there is a URL as a query param which has its own query parameters. Example below

Ex: https://test.domain.com?param1=a&ru=https://url2.domain.com/?url2paramA=A&url2paramB=B

In this example url2param2 is part of ru(redirect URL). when I try to retrieve ru parameter, its only giving the URL part with first parameter in it. Second query parameter its considered as part of main URL.

**Current Logic**

```js
const getParameterByName = (name, search) => {
  const match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(search);
  try {
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  } catch {
    return match && match[1];

  }
};

var result = getParameterByName('ru', 'https://test.domain.com?param1=a&ru=https://url2.domain.com/?url2paramA=A&url2paramB=B');
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Have you considered  using [new URL(url))](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to create a URL object that implements the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) so you can get the query parameters directly - no RegExp required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your redirect url is not encoded

```js
const getParameterByName = (name, search) => {
  const match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(search);
  try {
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  } catch {
    return match && match[1];
  }
};

const url = `https://test.domain.com/param1=a&ru=${encodeURIComponent('https://url2.domain.com/url2paramA=A&url2paramB=B')}`;

console.log(getParameterByName('ru', url))
```

Comment: ru decoded url value i need to send for some analytics as well as landing to the destination app.  But i understand whoever wants to add additional param they need to encode it, which is the only way

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you may use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) APIs:

```js
const plainUrl = 'https://test.domain.com?param1=a&ru=https://url2.domain.com/?url2paramA=A&url2paramB=B';

const url = new URL(plainUrl);

const result = url.searchParams.get('ru');

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to consider `paramB` as part of the `ru`, you would have to [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the second URL:

```js
const plainMainUrl = 'https://test.domain.com?param1=a';

const plainRedirectUrl = 'https://url2.domain.com/?url2paramA=A&url2paramB=B';

// option 1: manual

const plainUrl1 = `${plainMainUrl}&ru=${encodeURIComponent(plainRedirectUrl)}`;

const url1 = new URL(plainUrl1);

const result1 = url1.searchParams.get('ru');

// end option 1


// option 2: URLSearchParams#append

const url2 = new URL(plainMainUrl);

url2.searchParams.append('ru', plainRedirectUrl);

const result2 = url2.searchParams.get('ru');

// end option 2

console.assert(result1 === result2 && result2 === plainRedirectUrl);
console.log(result1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code works perfectly, but in this code you extract the url between `&` using regex that's why you didn't get the `url2paramB=B` after `&`, but you need to pass the redirect URL between any special characters like your given URL.

https://test.domain.com?param1=a&ru=**https://url2.domain.com/?url2paramA=A&url2paramB=B**

This URL contains a special character (two asterisks(`**`)) so you can extract the redirect URL between these asterisks(`*`).

Try this code:

```js
const getParameterByName = (name, search) => {
  const match = RegExp(`${name}=\\*{2}(.*?)\\*{2}`).exec(search);
  return match ? match[1] : null;
};

var result = getParameterByName('ru', 'https://test.domain.com?param1=a&ru=**https://url2.domain.com/?url2paramA=A&url2paramB=B**');
console.log(result)
```

Comment: ru url is something gets added while redirect if not authenticated by external teams. Can't ask every team to add url  between some special characters

Comment: @Satheesh Why would you need to ask the team to add the special characters? The URL in your question already has them

Comment: Yeah your provided url already have the special characters

Comment: Corrected it... Got added by formatting in the editor while trying to set bold.